# How can i find which application is restarting my Windows Service

Tags: c++, windows, windows-services, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a Windows Service which is written in C++. I have another background application to monitor this service, if this Windows service is stopped, then background application will start.

But i am seeing a strange thing is that my service Stops somehow(seeing logs in Application Log)  and starting(By background process). I didn't find any Application Error in Event Log.

Some other process or application is stopping my Windows Service.

I want to find out which application is stopping my service. Is there any tool to monitor the service stopping or C++ code can i write log to find who is requesting me to stop.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Library recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: The only way I know to determine which app is stopping your service is to hook `OpenService()` and `ControlService()` in every running process and look for `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP` requests for your service.